# What are "chkdisk" options for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, usb-storage, chkdsk

Such as -f and other options.

Back story for the curios: While using my my USB harddrive (NTFS) on Linux it gave me a warning that I should scan this disk drive under Windows and make sure it should be done with -f option.

Comment: Have you tried just using `chkdsk /?` to display the options? Or googling the command?

Comment: I see it now I tried 'chkdsk ?' and failed.

Comment: Just because an answer is Googlable doesn't make it any less valid for SE.

Comment: `help chkdsk` also works, as with any other command

Comment: It’s not `chkdsk ?` but `chkdsk /?`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### chkdsk syntax

To display the `chkdsk` options you can use `help chkdsk` or `chkdsk /?`

Notes:

- Some `chkdsk` commands will require the use of elevated privileges.
- See [chkdsk](http://ss64.com/nt/chkdsk.html) for examples and additional notes.

> **Syntax**
>
> ```
>   CHKDSK [drive:][[path]filename] [/F] [/V] [/R] [/L[:size]]
> ```
>
> **Key**
>
> - `[drive:]`   The drive to check.
> - `filename`   File(s) to check for fragmentation (FAT only).
> - `/F`         Automatically Fix file system errors on the disk.
> - `/X`         Fix file system errors on the disk, (Win2003 and above)
>               dismounts the volume first, closing all open file handles.
> - `/R`         Scan for and attempt Recovery of bad sectors.
> - `/V`         Display the full path and name of every file on the disk.
> - `/L:size`    NTFS only: change the log file size to the specified number of kilobytes. 
>               If size is not specified, displays the current log size and the drive type
>               (FAT or NTFS).
> - `/C`         Skip directory corruption checks.
> - `/I`         Skip corruption checks that compare directory entries to the
>               file record segment (FRS) in the volume's master file table (MFT)

Source [chkdsk](http://ss64.com/nt/chkdsk.html)

One additional option is not documented in the above source:

- `/B`              NTFS only: Re-evaluates bad clusters on the volume
                (implies `/R`)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [chkdsk](http://ss64.com/nt/chkdsk.html) - Check Disk - check and repair disk problems.